# Build a regex that does not contain the first and last character you are looking for in the match

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following problem.

This is what the regex looks like:

**var regexTest = new Regex(@"'\d.*\d@");**

This is what the string looks like:

**var text = "dsadsadsadsa('1.222222@dsadsa'";**

That is the result of what I would like to have:

**1.222222**

That's the result I'm getting right now ...:

**'1.222222@**

Answer (score 3):

You want to extract the float number in between `'` and `"`, use

```
var text = "dsadsadsadsa('1.222222@dsadsa'";
var regexTest = new Regex(@"'(\d+\.\d+)@");
var m = regexTest.Match(text);
if (m.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Here, `(\d+\.\d+)` *captures* any 1+ digits, `.` and then 1+ digits into Group 1 that you may access using `match.Groups[1].Value`. However, only access that value if there was a match, or you will get an exception (see `m.Success` part in my demo snippet).

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%27%28%5Cd%2B%5C.%5Cd%2B%29%40&i=dsadsadsadsa%28%271.222222%40dsadsa%27):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just enclose the part you want to get in parentheses, so that you can get it as a group:

```
var regexTest = new Regex(@"'(\d.*\d)@");
-----------------------------^------^----
```

Answer (score 0):

In `'\d.*\d@` you are are matching `'` followed by a digit, any character 0+ times followed by a digit. That would match `'1.222222@` but also for example `'1.A2@` because of the `.*`

To don't match the `'` and the `@` you could use a positive lookahead and a positive lookbehind to assert that they are there. If you only want to match digits then the `.*` could be left out.

`(?<=')\d+\.\d+(?=@)`

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%27%29%5cd%5c.%5cd%2b%28%3f%3d%40%29&i=dsadsadsadsa%28%271.222222%40dsadsa%27)

Comment: Could you elaborate how that differs from the answers using groups and what the pros/cons in contrast to them are?

Comment: I think the grouping approach is less steps which makes it faster. The lookaround approach does not use a capturing group.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I have just compared `'(\d+\.\d+)@` and `(?<=')\d+\.\d+(?=@)` against a `dsadsadsadsa('1.222222@dsadsa'` string at regexhero.net and the former pattern is reported to be 58.6% faster.

Comment: @ WiktorStribiżew Thank you for clarifying that, that's certainly a big difference.